# React: Replace String with a component like <span> for highlighting with color

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently looking for a solution to replace a Part of a larger String with a component to highlight this part.

I tried this:

```
function highlighted(text) {
    text.replace(highlightedPart, match => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{match}</span>;
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

but it seems like .replace isnt the right function for it. Since I get [Object, Object] inside the String. Is there a easy solution for it?

Comment: can you share more details about the result with example?

Comment: Does your string have multiple highlights or just one? I did this a few times

Comment: Just one, but for multipe it would be even better.  
I found this solution for one: 
```
function (text, toHighlight) => {
    if (!toHighlight) return text;
    return (
      <span key={toHighlight + text}>
        {text.split(toHighlight).reduce((prev, current, i) => {
          if (!i) {
            return [current];
          }
          return prev.concat(
            <span className={classes.highlightColor} key={toHighlight + current + i}>
              {toHighlight}
            </span>,
            current
          );
        }, [])}
      </span>
    );
  };
```